# Cross Street Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want the latitude and longitude of two street that cross from the Google Geocoding API.

It should be a simple matter to determine the syntax, but I am unable to find any examples.

I can, however, offer and example that doesn't work:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=maple+street+and+main+street,+Anywhere,+MO&sensor=false

The "and" keyword is wrong. Is there a proper syntax, or should I just kill myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the right syntax.  Your example doesn't work because there is no Anywhere, MO so the service is returning the only thing it recognized, which was the state of MO.

The API correctly returns locations of type `intersection` for the queries like:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Main%20Street%20and%201st%20Street,%20Springfield,%20MO&sensor=false
```

and

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Amphitheatre%20Parkway+and+Charleston%20Road,+Mountain%20View,%20CA&sensor=false
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that the address in my example is not valid. I was just sanitizing the data. Legitimate addresses, however, do return incorrect results based on the syntax that I've provided.

Comment: Once difference from my example to yours is the use of URL encoded spaces versus plus signs as separators. This I will test.